# Using React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML without the div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to adapt a React component so that it can be called from a regular non-React script. The particular component I am trying to get working is '[react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)'.

The HTML:

```
<div id="slides" style="display: none">
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" />
      <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-2.jpg" />
      <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
    </div>
<div>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Then in the 'react adaptor':

```
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

function renderCarousel(targetElementId, html) {
  const App = function() {
    return <Carousel>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
    </Carousel>;
  };

  render(<App />, document.getElementById(targetElementId));
}
```

Then the calling code that would be used by the non-React script:

```
renderCarousel("root", document.getElementById("slides").innerHTML);
```

The issue with this is that an extra 'div' is introduced which breaks the carousel's behaviour. Is there any way I can pass this HTML in such a way the inner HTML of div with id 'slides' is directly under the Carousel component or maybe there is another way of achieving the intended goal?

Note, this needs to work from an ES5 calling context.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something obvious about the question but couldn’t `children` be used in Carousel instead of html?

Comment: Maybe? An example would be useful to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood the issue, so the html you have there, would be all the slides right ?

What I would do is to pass the slides to the function as an array:

```
renderCarousel(targetElementId, slides)
```

so you can do something like:

```
function renderCarousel(targetElementId, slides=[]) {
  const App = function() {
    return <Carousel>
      {slides.map(html => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />)}
    </Carousel>;
  };

  render(<App />, document.getElementById(targetElementId));
}
```

it should work with something like:

```
const slides = Array.from(document.getElementById("slides").children)
renderCarousel("root", slides.map(slide=> slide.innerHTML))
```

Let me know how it goes !

Comment: This works, but for the part where it is called it should be noted arrow functions aren't part of ES5. Thank you for this. I have made a copy of this available at https://codesandbox.io/s/0qorv2m9q0

Comment: oh got it ! yeah you can move it to ES5, be careful with the Array.from, as it is not supported 100% neither in old browsers ! :)